# Pandas lambda function syntax error (with dictionary)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, lambda

I use lambda functions in Python a lot. All of a sudden, I cannot figure out why is there a syntax error message for this:

```
table['sp1 name'] = table['sp1'].apply(lambda x: sp1_new_dict[x] if x in sp1_new_dict.keys())
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: You're missing an `else` in the ternary `if` statement

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: simply, `sp1_new_dict[x] if x in sp1_new_dict.keys()` is not a valid expression, thus it cannot go there, hence the SyntaxError

Comment: lambda function must have a return value for every valid input hence the `else` expression must be provided

Answer (score 2):

You need an `else`. Boiling down your error:

```py
x = 1 if True

  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x = 1 if True
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


# No error here
x = 1 if True else 2
```

Since you are using a dictionary, maybe use `dict.get`:

```py
table['sp1 name'] = table['sp1'].apply(lambda x: sp1_new_dict.get(x))
```

Which returns `None` if the key isn't present